# Keeping a process running on server even SSH is closed

Tags: ssh, terminal, process, gnu-screen

I am running long program on server, which is basically Jar file of java program. I want to keep this program running even if SSH terminal is closed, how I can keep this program running on server?

Answer (score 22):

Two different ways:

1. Use `nohup` - by starting the program with `nohup /path/to/program &`, nohup keep the program running and any output will be redirected to the file `nohup.out` in the current directory
2. Use `screen` or `tmux` if either of them is installed on the server. They are a way to keep one or more shells going so that you can re-attach to them the next time you login - it's a much more powerful utility than nohup. `man screen` or `man tmux` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to keep a process running that you've already started without using nohup.

Suppose you started decompressing a large archive and now you want to go home.

```
$ tar -xzf bigfile.tar.gz
```

Press ctrl-z to send the processs to the background. You can type "jobs" and press enter and see the job number for your process, probably it's 1.

Then do:

```
$ disown %1
```

Answer (score 1):

Either screen or tmux will both work.

See for instance http://www.jeffstory.org/wordpress/?p=132 for a quick tutorial on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never used [Apache Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/), it may do what you want. It will run your Java program as a daemon, as a process in the background.

I'd then use [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/) to monitor this process, and shut it off if it takes up too many resources.

You will need to install htop apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Then run via

```
htop
```

When you see your process, you can kill it by selecting it in the list (via the arrow keys) and then kill it by pressing

```
f9, k
```