# Pass a command to ROOT from a shell script and having it stay open

Tags: shell, shell-script, command-line, input, cern-root

I am writing a bash script to perform some analysis using the program [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/). I want to run some initial command to load the result of the analysis, then continue using ROOT interactively.

The analysis part goes along well but the problem is that after `root` is executes my initial command, it closes immediately. So far I have tried the EOF (here-file) construct to pass my initial command and I am a bit unfamiliar with shell scripting so I would like to get your opinions on how to keep `ROOT` running after the execution of the script. That is I would like to see the ROOT prompt instead of the sytem prompt.

```
./runReader.py SummerStd 140PU_NM1 
root -l SummerStd_140PU_NM1_his.root << EOF
TBrowser a;
EOF
```

The above code executes the analysis then runs `root`; however, it immediately terminates and I have no time to inspect the TBrowser since I have the system prompt instead of the ROOT prompt. I would like control to stay at `root`'s command prompt after the script sends the `TBrowser` command to the program, so I can enter additional commands by hand.

Comment: How are you running this script? From a terminal? Or do you click on it in some file manager? Or something else?

Comment: @Gilles I run it through zsh from a terminal while logged in a remote terminal.

Comment: It's difficult to tell because you don't describe your whole problem. If the problem is that ROOT dies when you disconnect from the remote machine, then use screen or tmux: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131897/keeping-a-process-running-on-server-even-ssh-is-closed I'm closing this question as a duplicate. If this isn't what you meant, edit your question to clarify it and we can reopen it.

Comment: @Gilles Where did he say he was disconnecting from the remote system?

Comment: I think I now understand what he wants. `ROOT` is an interactive program with a command-line interface, and he wants the script to enter the first command into it, then revert to allowing him to type subsequent commands. I think the answer to this is to use `Expect`. I'm not going to revise my answer, because I don't have enough experience with Expect to show how to do it.

Comment: @Barmar Well Barmer thanks that is exactly what I want so you suggest me to look into the keyword Expect.

Comment: @Vesnog If you go to StackOverflow you can find a number of examples of what you want under the `expect` tag.

Comment: @Gilles I only require ROOT run as long as I am logged in. My point is that ROOT closes when the execution of the shell script finishes; I would like to have ROOT prompt in front of me with TBrowser open and ready for user input. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: ROOT does not close because the execution of the shell script finishes, it's the opposite: the shell script waits for ROOT to exit. I think that you want to keep ROOT running after it executes the `TBrowser` command and to be able to type more commands at ROOT's prompt, did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @Gilles Definitely that is what I want. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
expect -c 'spawn -noecho root -l SummerStd_140PU_NM1_his.root
           send "TBrowser a;\r"
           interact'
```

Comment: Should I write this directly inside the bash script?

Comment: @Vesnog, Yes, in place of your `root -l SummerStd_140PU_NM1_his.root << EOF...`

Comment: `expect: not found`
it fails to find a command `expect`

Answer (score 1):

With ROOT, this is actually easy. Once the `root` program has read the files passed on the command line, it continues to read interactive commands (unless you pass the `-q` option). So you can pass your startup commands in an additional file parameter, via an [extra file descriptor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor).

```
#!/bin/sh
./runReader.py SummerStd 140PU_NM1 
root -l SummerStd_140PU_NM1_his.root /dev/fd/3 3<<'EOF'
TBrowser a;
EOF
```

This is the best approach on Linux, FreeBSD and OSX, but `root` seems to ignore files that it sees as having a length of 0, so it might not work on some other [unix variants where `/dev/fd` is not a regular file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123602/portability-of-file-descriptor-links/123659#123659) such as Solaris (`/dev/fd` is a device file) or AIX and HP-UX (`/dev/fd` doesn't exist). If you need to run your script on these platforms, you can put your startup command in a temporary file¹. The `trap` command sets up `rm -f "$tmp_root"` to run when the script exits.

```
#!/bin/sh
./runReader.py SummerStd 140PU_NM1
tmp_root=tmp-$$.root
trap 'rm -f "$tmp.root"' EXIT HUP INT TERM
cat >tmp_root <<'EOF'
TBrowser a;
EOF
root -l SummerStd_140PU_NM1_his.root tmp.root
```

¹  <sub>I'm not using `mktemp` because it isn't available on some of the “exotic” (i.e. not Linux or *BSD) platforms that you'd use this script on.</sub>